# Validate TexBox Control For NULL/Empty values

Tags: vb.net

So i made a game in Vb and i first made a login form with only username. I made a pic, a button and a textbox. You obviobusly write your name in the textbox then press the button to continue to the game form.
What i need help is, you can enter the game without entering a name, how do i make the button locked until something is written in the textbox that then unlocks the button?

i haven't tried anything because i do not know how to begin, im quite new to vb but i just want this as an extra feature, even the "mini stuff" matters

Comment: In the Properties window, click the Locked property and select false.

Comment: That's not my question :p, i already know that

Comment: You must explain your question in order to avoid Negative Ranking then. Thanks

Comment: I've already  explained it fairly well. Ok, to start with: You open up the game: a login form appears, you have to write any username you want. When you do, you press the login button so you can continue to the game. I want that login button to be locked unless any letter is written in the textbox. When any letter is written, the button automaticly unlocks directly. The reason for this is you can enter the game without writing a username, i dont want that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your Button1 `Enabled` property to `False` by default. Then, in order to check if the TextBox1 was filled you can do something like:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object,
                 e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) Then
   Button1.Enabled = True
Else
   Button1.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: THANK YOU so much, worked perfectly and the code is simple to understand :)

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)` is not a good way to handle strings(`TextBox1.text`) because there is one caveat in your solution i.e it will not consider empty space `" "` (_what if `TextBox1.Text=" "`_ ?) see a live example here https://dotnetfiddle.net/fkydyT

Comment: @wingedpanther Yes, you are right, so you can Trim the argument in the String.IsNullOrEmpty().

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `TRIM()` to handle white spaces in `TextBox` control

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
     If Trim(TextBox1.Text) <> vbNullString Then
         Button1.Enabled = True
     Else
         Button1.Enabled = false
         MsgBox("You must enter name")
         TextBox1.Focus()
     End If
End Sub
```